# Асинхронная отрисовка элементов на vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

В приложении есть несколько вкладок и в одной из них список,скажем на 2000 элементов.
при смене вкладки vue.js должен заново отрисовать элементы и получается задержка,пока все не отрисуется.
Можно ли сделать,что б сперва отрисовывалось содержимое вкладки, а список с большим количеством элементов-позже-без подвисания приложения?

Answer (score 1):

Если список не на экране, то не надо его совсем отрисовывать - скрывайте его через v-if, а когда эта вкладка открывается - показывайте его.

Непосредственно по вопросу: так можно сделать, если ваш список скрыть изначально за v-if, а показывать его в хуке mounted.

Еще для больших списков можно посмотреть в сторону virtual scroll - технология, которая позволяет отрисовывать в DOM только видимые элементы и таким образом серьезно повышать производительность. Для Vue есть [vue-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller).